# Failed to load resources from resource file

Tags: .net, iis

Get the following error periodically in an IIS application:

> Failed to load resources from resource file.

The full error message in the Application Event Log is:

> Event Type:    Error
>   Event Source:  .NET Runtime
>   Event Category:    None
>   Event ID:  0
>   Date:      8/8/2008
>   Time:      8:8:8 AM
>   User:      N/A
>   Computer:  BLAH123
>   Description:
>   The description for Event ID ( 0 ) in Source ( .NET Runtime ) cannot be found. The >local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to >display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: .NET Runtime version 1.1.4322.2407- Setup Error: Failed to load resources from resource file
>   Please check your Setup.

Application is written in .NET 1.1 but the server runs ASP.NET 2.0.  Thanx.

Update: Meant to say ASP.NET 2.0 is installed but the default website folder, and the websites inside the folder, are set to ASP.NET 1.1.  On the website folder the ISAPI Filter is set to ASP.NET 2.0.  My first guess about the problem was having ASP.NET 1.1 and ASP.NET 2.0 running side by side.

Update 2: ASP.NET 2.0 is installed but all the websites run only ASP.NET 1.1 (long story and happened before I started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was asked before Server Fault, where it probably belongs.  Anyway, I never did figure out the error so assume it's closed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 apps running on the web server? We had some instances of a similar nature around here and the resolution we found was to create two app pools, one for 1.1 apps and one for 2.0 apps and to assign each application accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a different error without the ISAPI filter in place?

Answer (score 0):

This error sometimes occurs when a request happens at the exact time that you are rebuilding the application (after a web.config change or a plain recompilation) and IIS cannot find the file in the temporary folders.